# StreamReader reading MemoryStream to a string seems to be truncating end of file

Tags: c#, streamreader, memorystream

I am saving an HTML document to a MemoryStream and then reading that stream (using StreamReader) out to a string object. HtmlDocument object is complete but when I inspect the string that is assigned from the streamReader.ReadToEnd() it appears that the end of the file has been truncated. I assume that my implementation of the MemoryStream or StreamReader is faulty. Can someone help me out?

```
HtmlDocument htmlDocument = GetDocument(htmlHref);
HtmlNode scriptTag = htmlDocument.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//script[@id ='HwInitialize']");

scriptTag.InnerHtml =
    string.Format("org.myorg.application.init ={0};", stateJson);           

MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
htmlDocument.Save(memoryStream); //Save Document to memory
memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(memoryStream);
return streamReader.ReadToEnd(); //return the stream contents to string
```

Comment: StreamReader uses UTF-8 by default - how does HtmlDocument.Save store it?

Comment: How about using htmlDocument.DocumentNode.OuterHtml instead?

Comment: Both good questions/solutions.. Ill check

Comment: It appears that this might be a bug with the HTML Agility Pack. There is a proposed fix. I guess I can try this fix and build a new lib. http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/workitem/29233

Comment: @Simon My changes the html are present in the string returned from OuterHtml. If you add the answer.. I'll mark it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The htmlDocument.DocumentNode.OuterHtml property will serialize your htmlDocument, including any of your changes, into a html string.